# how to create a new field in CRM 2015?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-4

I'm using `Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 on-permise` I need to create new field multi select lookup
thanks.

Comment: Have you at least put some effort into trying to find this out yourself?  Like reading the docs or google it?

Comment: I searched everywhere for solution, but I could not find it anywhere.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question asked by many clients - I disagree with the downvote(s).  James Wood is right, there is no way to truly create this in CRM, although you can approximate it in a number of ways (i.e. javascript/html, 1:N relationships, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant, that feature doesn't exist unfortunately.

There are some multi select lookup fields in CRM but those are limited to system fields which cant be customised.

The closest you can get is a 1:M or M:M relationship which will appear as a grid.

Comment: I want field like recipient in entity phone call (activities)

Comment: Yeah, you cant do that

Comment: how can do that ? please